# Btree searching on non index field

Tags: mysql, postgresql, rdbms

I have been reading this answer by @XenphYan

[How does database indexing work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108/how-does-database-indexing-work)

But there are few things I'm unable to understand

> Due to the fact that a number of records can only be sorted on one
>   field, we can state that searching on a field that isn’t sorted
>   requires a Linear Search which requires N/2 block accesses (on
>   average), where N is the number of blocks that the table spans. If
>   that field is a non-key field (i.e. doesn’t contain unique entries)
>   then the entire table space must be searched at N block accesses.

Firstly I unable to understand the above part.

**Question 1.** How come searching on a field that isn't sorted would requires a Linear Search N/2 block accesses?

> Whereas with a sorted field, a Binary Search may be used, this has
>   log2 N block accesses. Also since the data is sorted given a non-key
>   field, the rest of the table doesn’t need to be searched for duplicate
>   values, once a higher value is found. Thus the performance increase is
>   substantial.

I fail to understand this part too, it seem to me the above point specific that on a sorted field one can employ Binary Search.

What I feel ...
as per my understanding a Binary Search are applied only to index field. (i.e To improve search performance)

POC:

Here how my table looks like

```
create table sqltemp(
  id INT PRIMARY KEY, 
  name CHAR(50),
  counter INT
);

insert into sqltemp(id,name,counter) values(1,'viren',1),(2,'vikas',2),(3,'vikram',3);  

EXPLAIN ANALYZE  select id from sqltemp where counter=2;

Seq Scan on sqltemp  (cost=0.00..14.25 rows=2 width=4)
   Filter: (increment = 2)
```

Atleast the EXPLAIN command does not specific that any Binary Search Sign (i.e it does a `Seq Scan`)

So, My question 2 is

**Question 2:** Is my understand correct that Binary Search in DB are only applicable for indexed field.

Answer (score 0):

> Question 1. How come searching on a field that isn't sorted would requires a Linear Search N/2 block accesses?

The important part is *on average*. If you're searching for one item out of N, 50% of the time, it'll happen to be in the first half of the items that you check. This is just a fancy way of saying that there's no quicker way of finding the target than checking each row.

> Question 2: Is my understand correct that Binary Search in DB are only applicable for indexed field.

A `sequential scan` means that the database engine is looking at each row, which is O(n). If you write a query that takes advantage of an index, the EXPLAIN will instead tell you that it is able to use an `index scan`, which is O(log2(n)), which is *much faster* on large tables. To see this in your example database, try:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE  select * from sqltemp where id=2;
```

The primary key is an indexed field, which means that the database engine is storing it in a binary tree.

Comment: Ruekert So, my understanding is correct one cannot perform a binary search on field that aren't index. right?